# Outlook specify mailbox in search query

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, query, mailbox

[image: Outlook screenshot]

Is it possible to specify the mailbox in the search query itself instead of using the dropdown on the left ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the mailbox can only be change manually on the left dropdown. If you always need to search in a scope, it's suggested that you could change the default scope via File>Options>Search, as shown in the below figure.

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.